# Rails import scss file for specific layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

In my app I have 2 layouts, one used for the app itself and one used for the site (about us, contacts etc..).

I have imported scss files for app layout on application.css.scss.

Now I am trying to import some other scss file to be applied on site layout only, to not mess app layout.

These files use variables like $white.

The suggestion I have seen is to apply a scss file to a specific layout is to import it in the layout file itself with for instance `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "variables" %>`

But variables fail to be seen. I understand that this isn't working because for files to be processed as sass I need to use @import on application.css.scss. But if I do that they are applied everywhere.

scss files are placed in vendor folder.

Are my assumptions correct? Is there an alternative way to achieve what I want?

Comment: "But variables fail to be seen" I think SASS variables don't appear in the final CSS. only the CSS rules get outputted.

Comment: I am talking about development env, before precompiling, if that matters..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your best option is to use a different css for each layout (`application.scss` and `theother.scss`) since variables need to be applied at assets precompilation time.

`theother.scss` would be something like:

```
/*
*= require 'variables'
*= require 'application'
*/
```

Maybe you'll need to change the `require 'application'` with all the `require` inside it if you need your `variables` file to override other variables though.

You then add `theother.scss` as an asset to be precompiled on rails config:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( theother.css )
```

And finally, on one layout you use:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "application"
```

and on the other you use:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "theother"
```